# How to run multi javascript functions onPageFinished android

Tags: javascript, android, function

I m coding a `WebView` application that should call some **javascript** functions everytime a page is loaded

This is what I ve done but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
    String url = "http://catcheat.net/test/test.html";
   faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction()");
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
               view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction2()");
          }
        }
    };

}
}
```

Everything goes well Untill i reach the clickfunction2(). I can't call this second function
Where I m wrong??

Comment: what are you added here in faller .setJavaScriptEnabled there is no need for this

Comment: webview is just simple to do like i m posting here is code

Comment: Link  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted this link also

Comment: sample example are here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: the problem is not faller.setJavaScriptEnabled. The problem is that I can't call clickFunction2(). Everything goes well untill calling clickfunction() bu after it doesn't proceed

Comment: have you look my links i have posted here have u still read if u read these links then u find you will do it by these codes .. just read and do it by self

Comment: I have read. But There isn't any note about call  differents javascript fuctions everytime a new page is loaded. It explains how to open url on the webview. And this is just the first part of my code and in that part there is no problem. My problem is at the end when I ve to col the clickfunction2()

Comment: Oh sorry I m watching now the first tut. I didn't see that link

Comment: Even at that link is there anything that can help me sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a syntax error.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
String url = "http://catcheat.net/test/test.html";
faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl(url);
 view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction()");
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction2()");
      }
    }
   });

 }
 }
```

It's }); and not };

Comment: It does not work for me. Inner onPageFinished() has never fired.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: scrap the answer before, as there is a bigger issue: calling a loadUrl from inside the onPageFinished could cause an infinite loop. Note that one should be careful when invoking loadUrl inside onPageFinished.

Actually, and apart from parenthesis and colons (which you should have seen while trying to compile) the issue may be the order of the loadUrl. These should be invoked after the corresponding setWebViewClient:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings faller = view.getSettings();
    String url = "http://catcheat.net/test/test.html";
    faller.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {}
            });
            view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction()");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:clickFunction2()");
        }
    });
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```